# Control+F (Find functionality) is not working correctly with Extjs grid

Tags: extjs-grid, extjs6-classic

Control+F (Find functionality) is not working correctly with Extjs 6.0.1. 
If we perform find functionality in extjs Grid which is having 50 records,it shows results for given search. But if we reload grid with records count greater than 50, control+F does not gives correct result. It shows search result only in first 50 records though further records also has matched search keyword. 
We have tried same on Extjs kitchenSink demo example, but failed to get expected output. 
We have made reference fiddle for this - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/145s

Also we noticed Control+F functionality shows different results in different browsers for same keyword.[Attached reference screenshots][[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNNS0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome gave me also 24 result.
However, your are checking the search functionality of the browser here, which will depend on how the browser made the search but also might depend on how the dom element are render,etc...

I don't know what you are trying it achieve, but in my point of view, if you are looking to some way of searching across a ExtJs grid, you should check : http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/classic/grid/live-search-grid.html

Which will really search accord the records! (and not depend on which are showed or not).
And if you want to bind this to Ctrl+F, you should us a a KeyMap (see https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.util.KeyMap)

Comment: Eh I think it's pretty obvious what he wants to achieve: Frameworks should not break browser features like ctrl+f. Rows that haven't been scrolled into view should be loaded into the DOM by default unless you've got 10,000 of them. I guess the solution is to not touch crap like extjs